# Why JUnit Test Suite is not detecting JUnit Test cases?

Tags: java, junit

I am using Eclipse latest version and JUnit4 in it.

As I tried to create '**JUnit Test Suit**' for the existing '**JUnit Test Cases**' it is not detecting the test cases. I created without inclusion and I added JUnit Test Cases manually and ran the JUnit Test Suite, It is not going through all the test cases even after adding them manually.

I attempted to create another JUnit Test Suite file then it is started to detect JUnit Test Suite file which I created initially.

Answer (score 0):

Need to select specific JUnit 4 Test, shouldn't use JUnit Jupiter Test.
Only test cases which are created in JUnit 4 Test will be detected by the JUnit 4 suite.